# Jetpack Compose fails with NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroidx/compose/runtime/MutableStateKt;

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I built an app to play around with Jetpack compose. Everything worked fine until alpha-11 but since I tried to update it to alpha-12 (or even to beta-1) the app fails at runtime with the error `NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroidx/compose/runtime/MutableStateKt;`

additionally saying  :

`Didn't find class "androidx.compose.runtime.MutableStateKt" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.APPNAME-TeAYAMsRf0C9pLQOdWShCA==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.APPNAME-TeAYAMsRf0C9pLQOdWShCA==/lib/x86, /system/lib, /system/product/lib]]`

The error is caused by the use of `MutableState` and `mutableStateOf` which are both imported from androidx.compose.runtime but I couldn't find any info anywhere...

Here the dependencies block[image: Dependencies block]

Comment: Usually this type of problem means one of your dependencies is built against an older version of Compose. Can you include your `dependencies` block?

Comment: This sounds like version mismatch

Comment: This strange error once happened to me, and the fix was more strange. I had to remove all EMPTY `remember {mutableStateOf(...)}` in my code. But once they had values (of any type), the error was gone.

Comment: Dependencies block added

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved the issue by upgrading to BETA and following all the steps in this gist https://gist.github.com/mitchtabian/f1327d392e3c0ab9ac416c91204c329b

I cannot say for sure what had caused the issue but it was most probably a version mismatch so thanks to the ones who pointed me to it.

Answer (score 1):

---

I faced similar isue
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroidx/compose/ui/text/input/TextInputForTests;

but adding this to build.gradel file in side android{} block resolved my issue

### Kotlin DSL

```
kapt {
        correctErrorTypes = true
    }
```

### Grovee

```
kapt {
        correctErrorTypes  true
    }
```

Answer (score -5):

This error typically occurs when the required class or dependency is not present in the classpath. In your case, it seems that the androidx.compose.runtime.MutableStateKt class is missing from the classpath.

To resolve this issue, make sure you have the necessary dependencies and libraries configured correctly in your project. Specifically, ensure that you have the required version of the Android Compose library (androidx.compose.runtime) available and properly linked to your project.

Here are a few steps you can take to troubleshoot and resolve the issue:

1. Check your project dependencies: Verify that the required Android
   Compose libraries are correctly specified in your project's build
   file (e.g., build.gradle or build.gradle.kts). Ensure you have the
   necessary dependencies and that they are up to date.
2. Refresh dependencies: In IntelliJ IDEA, you can try refreshing your
   project dependencies by clicking the "Refresh" button in the Gradle
   tool window. This action will update your project's dependencies
   according to the specified configurations.
3. Clean and rebuild: Perform a clean build of your project to ensure
   that all the necessary files are generated and compiled correctly.
   In IntelliJ IDEA, you can choose the "Build" -> "Clean Project"
   option, followed by "Build" -> "Rebuild Project" to initiate a clean
   build process.
4. Check for conflicting dependencies: It's possible that there may be
   conflicting dependencies or version mismatches causing the issue.
   Review your project's dependencies and check for any conflicts or
   inconsistencies. You can use tools like gradle-dependency-analyze or
   IntelliJ IDEA's built-in dependency analysis to identify and resolve
   any conflicts.

Double-checking your project configuration, dependencies, and ensuring that the necessary libraries are correctly specified and available should help resolve the NoClassDefFoundError related to androidx.compose.runtime.MutableState.

Comment: This feels like an AI written answer